# Spring MVC Binding: How to find if bind action was successful

Tags: data-binding, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC `form:select` whose `form:options` are bind with a `List<Custom_Object>`. The `List<Custom_Object>` is named as `LOCALIZATION_LIST` in the code below.

The `path` attribute of `form:select` is used to set the selected option.

```
<form:form action="editNode.do" method="post" name="editNodeForm" commandName="editElementDetails">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Data Type</td>
      <td>
       <form:select path="datatype" onchange="" cssClass="large" id="datatypes">
        <c:if test="${! empty LOCALIZATION_LIST}">
          <form:options items="${LOCALIZATION_LIST}" itemLabel="local_Name" itemValue="local_Name"/>
        </c:if>
       </form:select>
      </td>
    </tr>   
  </table>
</form:form>
```

Now my problem is that there might be a scenario when `editElementDetails.datatype` may contain a value which is not there in `LOCALIZATION_LIST` at all. So currently Spring MVC shows the first element of `LOCALIZATION_LIST` as selected.

Is there a way I can figure out whether the bind action for setting the selected object in `form:options` of `form:select` was successful or not?

So that when the binding was not successful, I can then add one extra form:option with the new value in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: Answering my own question**

I figured it out for now by manually searching for the incoming command object field value in the `LOCALIZATION_LIST` and if not found, adding an extra `form:option` corresponding to it.

I was hoping to find a JSTL/Spring-MVC out-of-box solution for this though.

Here is the code:

```
<form:form action="editNode.do" method="post" name="editNodeForm" commandName="editElementDetails">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Data Type</td>
      <td>
       <form:select path="datatype" onchange="" cssClass="large" id="datatypes">
        <c:if test="${! empty LOCALIZATION_LIST}">
          <c:set var="contains" value="false" />
          <c:forEach var="item" items="${LOCALIZATION_LIST}">
            <c:if test="${item eq editElementDetails.datatype}">
              <c:set var="contains" value="true" />
            </c:if>
          </c:forEach>
          <c:if test="${ !contains }">
            <form:option label="${editElementDetails.datatype}" value="${editElementDetails.datatype}"/>
          </c:if>
          <form:options items="${LOCALIZATION_LIST}" itemLabel="local_Name" itemValue="local_Name"/>
        </c:if>
       </form:select>
      </td>
    </tr>   
  </table>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is the process of validating a form submission that is what I understood (maybe got you all wrong).You can use [Spring-Validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) here is one nice tutorial about using it.

[Spring Form validation](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-validation-1.html) . Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah even I was wondering if I was able to phrase my question properly or not.  :|  But let me try again: Form validation works **after form-submission** whereas my intention is to work at the time the form is being rendered and a select list is being created.   At render-time, how to find if my form:options binding has worked fine and the the commandObject field has been found in the list of customObjects associated with form:options. Hope that made sense.

Comment: You can set an additional boolean flag on the server side code from where you have constructed your form object.Then you need to just check for flag value to decide which select box to display.